# "Blog" link on offline page links to wrong blog

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks, offline, maintenance

The blog link on the SO offline page links to [blog.serverfault.com](http://blog.serverfault.com).

Since [blog.stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com) is the main SE blog, it makes sense that issues regarding the maintenance would be posted there.  Should this link be updated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Server Fault blog is run by the SE server administrators, who are responsible for the uptime and maintenance of the SE servers. Thus, they would post appropriate server information on their blog.