# Why does the Meta Stack Overflow site maintenance page link to the Server Fault blog?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, meta, maintenance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [“Blog” link on offline page links to wrong blog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98050/blog-link-on-offline-page-links-to-wrong-blog)

The [Meta Stack Overflow maintenance page](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/app_offline.htm) reads:

> ## Meta Stack Overflow is currently offline for maintenance
>
> ---
>
> Routine maintenance usually takes less than an hour. If this turns
> into an extended outage, we will post details on the [blog](http://blog.serverfault.com/).

Why is Server Fault's blog linked? It seems like that would be an odd place to post extended outage messages about Meta Stack Overflow. (If anything, I would have expected the [Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com) to be linked instead.) Is this intentional?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98050/blog-link-on-offline-page-links-to-wrong-blog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intentional, our sysadmins post to the Server Fault blog (server maintenance/upkeep/etc is in scope more-so on Server Fault is about), so it's where they'll post any extended outage info.