# "We are Offline" page for Stack Overflow has a link to the Server Fault blog

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Blog” link on offline page links to wrong blog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98050/blog-link-on-offline-page-links-to-wrong-blog)

The text below links to the Server Fault blog instead of the Stack Overflow blog:

> Routine maintenance usually takes less than an hour. If this turns
>   into an extended outage, we will **post details on the [blog](http://blog.serverfault.com/)**.

Comment: I hold my hands up, btw; blame me for that little.... hiccough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the maintenance is handled by the system administrators over at Server Fault. They write on that blog about their ideas and interests, as well as server related stuff.

The Stack Overflow blog is for Stack Overflow related news and events - not downtime. This is likely because regular visiters to the blog don't care about our server upgrades and outages, they're looking for Podcasts and CHAOS news.